# How to search a string-defined range for a value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

1. Search a column for a match, value = a
2. Return the row of that match -> row(a)
3. Search in row(a) for a match, value = b
4. Return the column of that match -> col(b)
5. Return the cell value at location: row(a),cell(b)

So far, I am able to do steps 1/2 with this:

```
    =MATCH("a",P$1:$P$100,0)
```

which returns the row that "a" is found in

However I am running into difficulty searching in row(a) for the column that matches the location of b.

What can I do to fix this?

P.S. for step 5, I can use this given col(b) = 10

```
    =INDEX($A$1:$O$100,MATCH("a",P$1:$P$100,0),10)
```

Comment: is `b` a header in the first row, because as you have it the return would either be an error or `b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add another match to the INDEX

If the value `b` is a header to find in the first row:

```
 =INDEX($A$1:$O$100,MATCH("a",P$1:$P$100,0),MATCH("b",$A$1:$O$1,0))
```

If the value `b` is in the same row:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$O$100,MATCH("a",P$1:$P$100,0),MATCH("b",=INDEX($A$1:$O$100,MATCH("a",P$1:$P$100,0),0),0))
```

The upper will return the value from the row where a is found in column P and b is found in the first row.

The lower will return `b` or an error depending on whether `b` is found in the same row that `a` is found in Column P